# Why is !null true when var is null per default

Tags: javascript

Why is JavaScript executing the code below even though the var is initially declared as null? The condition in the if-query is that the var interval **is not null** but it is, so actually it should not be executed.

```js
let interval = null;

if (!interval) {
  setInterval(print, 1000);
}

function print() {
  console.log('Hi');
}
```

Comment: What do you expect !null to be and why?

Comment: Because `!interval` is not a comperison. you invert the `null` value. Just go to console and type in `!null` you will see true. What you want is to compare it `interval !== null`

Comment: I expect: !null = everything but not null because the exclamation mark means not and when i say not null I mean everything like strings, int, undefined but not null

Comment: That statement makes 0 sense. The !whatever can only have two possible results. true or false. Which one do you expect and why for !null ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

null is one of a few 'falsy' values in JavaScript, including NaN, false, 0, "" and undefined. When JavaScript is asked to coerce a value to bool, which `if` does, the value is checked against falsy values, but is otherwise considered 'truthy'. Your null was falsy, you used `!` to 'not' it, making it true.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has a concept called Type Coercion.

> Type coercion is the process of converting value from one type to another (such as string to number, object to boolean, and so on). Any type, be it primitive or an object, is a valid subject for type coercion.
> https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/

In this case, `null` is coerced to false and then negated(true). That's why `setInterval()` is being executed.

The *if statement* has implicit coercion (automatic coercion) for some types: Objects, string, numbers and so on.

If you're not sure what the if statement will coerce to, you could try *explicit coercion*. For example, execute this in console `Boolean(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

`!null` is `true`

```js
console.log(!null)
```

Your code is equivalent of:

```
let interval = null ;
const value = !inteval;

if(value) {
setInterval(print,1000);
}

function print() {
console.log('Hi');
}
```

As `value` (`!null`) is true, the code in `if` block runs

> The condition in the if-query is that the var interval is not null

It doesn't work like that, from you description the code should look like this:

```
let interval = null;
if (interval !== null) {
  //..
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I do not understand why it is true

Comment: Because in 1995 when JavaScript was created someone thought that it would be a great idea to make this operator work not only with boolean types. [falsy values[(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) have been chosen. `!falsy` always returns true. If you want to know what values are converted to `true` check the table in the link I sent.

Answer (score 0):

To not execute you would do

```js
if (interval) {
  setInterval(print, 1000);
}
```

meaning if condition is falsy, which it does `(interval = null = falsy)`, it won't execute.